# Excelsior error: classpath does not contain main classes

Tags: java, class, netbeans, classpath, exe

I try to make an `exe` file of a `jar` file. I get a error like this:

> "classpath does not contain main classes"

This error is from the program Excelsior.

Comment: Please add the commands you were trying, JARs added to classpath, path from which command is invoked to make exe file

Comment: The question is - why do you want to do that? If you just want your users to be able to double-click your application you just need a runnable jar file.

Comment: when i copy the file from "project/dist/" to a usb it will do nothing when i click it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest file should be like-

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_67 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: MyMainClass
Class-Path: .
```

You must have missed "Main-Class" or "Class-Path" attribute.
You can manually add these entries by editing manifest file.

Also, if you are looking for other alternatives, this will help you-
[How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)